# Integral of Product of Multivariate Gaussian PDF

Tags: probability, integration, functions, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

All,

I see from [The Matrix Cookbook](http://compbio.fmph.uniba.sk/vyuka/ml/old/2008/handouts/matrix-cookbook.pdf) Section 8.1.8 that there is a nice formula for the product of two multivariate Gaussian PDFs as a scalar times a Gaussian PDF. That's crisp. My issue is massaging an equation into the required form. It's basically part of a weird filtering problem I've encountered. I am going to end up integrating over all $x_k$ in the following equation
$$ L = \int f(x_k)\cdot \mathcal{N}_{x_k}(\mu,\Sigma_1)\cdot \mathcal{N}_{x_{k+1}}(\mathbf{A}x_k + \mathbf{b},\Sigma_2) \,\text{d}x_k \tag{1}$$
and I am hoping (praying) that $L$ will also be proportional to a Gaussian PDF.

I know that the PDF of $x_{k+1}$ is just $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A}\mu + \mathbf{b}, \Sigma_2 + \mathbf{A}^T\Sigma_1\mathbf{A})$, which is what I'd get if I did not have $f(x_k)$ (I think). But with $f(x_k)$, I am not sure.

**In short:**
Can anyone help derive the scaling, mean, and covariance of the Gaussian PDF represented by (1)? I tried for a few hours but got nowhere. Thanks!

Comment: It might help to clarify your question a little. Are you saying $x_k \sim N(\mu, \Sigma_1)$ and $x_{k+1}\mid x_k \sim N(Ax_k + b, \Sigma_2)$? What is $f(x_k)$?

Comment: Exactly. Is there better notation I should use? The key is that I'm using the probability distributions, not drawing samples. Like I want $L(x_{k+1})$ as a function of $x_{k+1}$. $f(x_k)$ happens to be a Gaussian CDF, but I don't need analytic solutions to the integrals, I am just looking for the integrals representing the scaling, mean, and covariance of the Gaussian PDF that represents $L$. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if I've understood correctly, you have $x_k \sim N(\mu, \Sigma_1)$, $x_{k+1} \mid x_k \sim N(Ax_k + b, \Sigma_2)$, and you want to know the distribution of $x_{k} \mid x_{k+1}$, so you can compute expressions like $\mathbb E[f(x_k) \mid x_{k+1}]$.

In general, this is just a [conditional normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions). We have

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_k \\ x_{k+1}\end{pmatrix} \sim N\left(\begin{pmatrix}\mu_1\\\mu_2\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} \\ \Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22}\end{pmatrix}\right),$$
where $\mu_1 = \mu$, $\mu_2 = A\mu + b$, $\Sigma_{11}=\Sigma_1$, $\Sigma_{12} = \Sigma_{21}^T = \Sigma_1A^T$, and $\Sigma_{22} = \Sigma_2 + A\Sigma_1A^T.$ The conditional distribution is then
$$x_k \mid x_{k+1} \sim N(\bar\mu, \bar\Sigma),$$
where $\bar\mu = \mu_1 +\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(x_{k+1}-\mu_2)$, and $\bar\Sigma =\Sigma_{11} - \Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{21}$.

You can then compute
$$L = \mathbb E[f(x_k)\mid x_{k+1}]\ p(x_{k+1}),$$
where $p$ is the density of $x_{k+1}$,
by integrating over $x_{k} \mid x_{k+1}$. Whether or not $L$ is proportional to a normal density will depend on the function $f$; it is not true in general.

Comment: This seems like it's in the right direction, but I definitely have questions. It seems wise to think about this as an EV problem. To me, $L=\int f(x_k) P(x_k, x_{k+1})$. Is that correct? Is that equal to $\mathbb{E}[f(x_k) | x_{k+1}]$? Maybe if I could massage this into a better form, your answer would be clear, but I'm not quite there yet lol. Really appreciate the help

Comment: To clarify, $P(x_k, x_{k+1})$ is the joint probability. That's what I thought I needed, rather than $P(x_k|x_{k+1})$, but if you can explain why I'm wrong, that would be awesome. If my expression for $L$ in the comment above is correct, I think I'd need the joint, not the conditional

Comment: You want $\int f(x_k) P(x_k, x_{k+1}) dx_{k} = \int f(x_k) P(x_k \mid x_{k+1}) P(x_{k+1})dx_k = \mathbb E[f(x_k) \mid x_{k+1}] P(x_{k+1})$, as the last part drops out of the integral. @TylerKlein

Comment: Ah, okay, that checks out. However, that would still give me, at best, the product of two Gaussian PDFs $P(x_{k+1})$ and the integral, so I'm not much better off in terms of a compact solution. There is a paper with a similar problem that appears to claim $L(x_{k+1})$ is a scaled Gaussian PDF scalar is $c=\int f(x_k)$ but they are approximating the integral by sampling, so it isn't clear what similar expressions for the mean and covariance might be. It seems like you have gotten us down a good route - any tips to continue?

Comment: Product of two normal pdfs might be what you want? If you've integrated out $x_k$ as above, and are left with two normal pdfs in $x_{k+1}$, their product is probably proportional to some other normal pdf.

Comment: Otherwise, yes, you can approximate $L$ by a normal pdf, though what approximation you want, and how good it is, will depend on the context. @TylerKlein

Comment: I think we are close, but I think I can create a more concise, lower level question which might be easier to answer. I appreciate all the help you provided, tho I am not sure if we actually got the final answer here. I think it basically boils down to trying to represent the conditional PDF with $x_{k+1}$ as the random variable as a PDF with $x_k$ as the random variable (the functions should be exactly equal for all $x_k$ and $x_{k+1}$ but should be written as a PDF of $x_{k+1}$ if that makes sense.